# Pass values to javascript array filter?

Tags: javascript

How can one pass a variable to a filter function in javascript?

In this case I'm trying to pass a value to variable "maxage":

```
var dateFilter = function(value,maxage) { // Age in miliseconds
    if(Date.now() - value < maxage) {
        return value;
        } else {
        return false;
        }
    }

    dates.filter(dateFilter,500);
```

How can I pass the value `500` to the filter as `maxage`?

Comment: I'm trying to pass 500 to the filter as variable maxage

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You would need to invoke `Function.prototype.bind` to create something similar to a *default argument*.

```
dates.filter(dateFilter.bind( null, 500 ));
```

`dateFilter` callback would then called with `500` PLUS "*automatic passed in values*" `value, index, array`.

```
function dateFilter( customArgument, value, index, array ) {
    // customArgument === 500
}
```

Comment: You have it turned around. The bound argument is first, and the others are passed after. Like this: `function dateFilter( customArgument, value, index, array ) {`

Comment: @IHateLazy: did I say nope ? O_o

Comment: I didn't hear anything... ;-)

Answer (score 10):

`maxage` has been bound to `this`. Consider the following:

```
var dateFilter = function(value) {
  if(value < this) return value;
}
var dates = [1,2,3];
console.log(dates.filter(dateFilter,2));
> [1] // Output.
```

The [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) shows the `filter` signature to be `array.filter(callback[, thisObject])`

Answer (score 3):

Maybe there is no need to overcomplicate the things, try the simple way:

```
var maxage = 500,
    newDates = dates.filter(function(value) {
        return Date.now() - value < maxage;
    });
```